# 5D tensor in Theano

Tags: python, theano, symbolic-computation

I was wondering how to make a 5D tensor in Theano.

Specifically, I tried `dtensor = T.TensorType('float32', (False,)*5)`. However, the only issue is that `dtensor.shape`returns: `AttributeError: 'TensorType' object has no attribute 'shape'`

Whereas if I used a standard tensor type like`dtensor = T.tensor3('float32')`, I don't get this issue when I call `dtensor.shape.`
Is there a way to have this not be an issue with a 5D tensor in Theano?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theano variables do not have explicit shape information since they are **symbolic** variables, not numerical. Even `dtensor3 = T.tensor3(T.config.floatX)` does not have an explicit shape. When you type `dtensor3.shape` you'll get an object `Shape.0` but when you do `dtensor3.shape.eval()` to get its value you'll get an error.

For both cases however, `dtensor.ndim` works and prints out `5` and `3` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I guess I was more asking if there is a way to specify dtensor as a 5D tensor in order for dtensor.shape to not return AttributeError: 'TensorType' object has no attribute 'shape'?

Comment: Well although both variables are symbolic variables and they both do not have any real **shape** but I myself am confused on why the first one does not even have the attribute shape. I am going to do an investigation on it and will post the results when found a clue.

Comment: I think I know why. dtensor.shape does not work, but dtensor().shape does in fact work.

Comment: @user19346 so what is the reason for it?

Answer (score 1):

```
dtensor = T.TensorType('float32',(False,)*5)
```

only calls the function `TensorType`. In order to use the attribute `dtensor.shape` you need to make it an object. You can do it by:

```
dtensor = T.TensorType('float32',(False,)*5) ()
```

You can specify the name inside the parenthesis at the end if you wish.